# If none of the digits $~0,1,2,3,4~~$ be repeated, then what happens with the following problem?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am stuck with the 2nd part of following problem :

If none of the digits $~0,1,2,3,4~~$ be repeated , how many numbers of $~5~$ significant digit can be formed with them?  How many of them are divisible by $4~$?

My Try :  (Edit : after following the suggestion of @insipidintegrator )

A number is divisible by $4$ if last two digits form a number which is divisible by $4.$ Now last $2$-digit numbers  can be $~04,40,20,12,32.$

If last 2-digit numbers are $~~04, 40,~20$ then $1$st place can be filled in by 3 digits which means for first place , there are $3$ options . Since repetition is not allowed for $2$nd place and $3$ rd places, there are $~3,2,1~$ options respectively. So, for this case there are $~3 \times 2=6~$ choices for each .

If last $2$-digit numbers are $~~12,24,32,~$ first place can be filled in by 3 digits which means for first place , there are $2$ options(Since at first place zero can not be placed) . Since repetition is not allowed for 2nd place and 3 rd places, there are $~2,2,1~$ options respectively. So, for this case there are $~2 \times 2=4~$ choices for each .

Hence, total of $~ 3 \times 2+3 \times 2+3 \times 2+2 \times 2+2 \times 2+2 \times 2=30~$ numbers are divisible by $~4.$

Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: You missed ending with 24

Comment: Thanks.. Problem solved.